# Error with AMPscript variable declaration in Free Form block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, variable

I've added a snippet of AMPscript into a Template Based Email to add 30 days to a date in my footer.

As the email is Template Based, I have inserted the code via a Free Form Block at the top of my email.

My code is erroring due to an ***'expected comma is not found in the variable declaration'***. However, the variable has been declared in the correct manner.

Have I missed something?

```
%%[VAR @today, @plusOneMonth

SET @today =  AttributeValue('Created_Date')
SET @plusOneMonth = DateAdd(@today, 30, 'D')
SET @plusOneMonth = DateAdd(@today, 1, 'M')]%%

/*HTML*/
<p>%%=v(@plusOneMonth)=%%</p>
```

Here is the error message.
[image]

Comment: Do not put this in a free form block, use a code snippet instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you put it in the text area and this will transform everything into html code then cause this error.

In the Free form block, you can open the "HTML Editor" tab and try to put the code again. This code is fine from my end.

[image]

Comment: And yes, like @zuzannamj recommended above, you should put it in a code snippet. It would help you much to retain the code format